# How to make input field editable on toggle with redux based on toggle?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

Problem is that I want use **Redux** and based on the **edit toggle** (`product.editable`) it should be checked if the text are editable.

But everything goes well until it reaches the point that I want to edit the value that is inside the input field.

I need someone who could help me to the right direction. I know the JSON cannot be modified directly, but how can I change the current value and then make it editable inside the input field. Keep in mind I am using dumb components.

**Component:**

```
let getProductList = productList.map((product, i) => {
  return (
    <div key={i}>   
      {product.editable ?   
        <div>
          <input name="title" ref={(input) => title = input} value={product.title}/>
          <input name="description" ref={(input) => description = input} value={product.description}/>
        </div>
      : 
        <div>
          <div>{product.title}</div>
          <div>{product.description}</div>
      </div>}
      <ProductButtons productId={product._id} index={i}/>
    </div>
  ) 
});

export const ProductButtons = ({ productId, index}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(deleteItem(productId, index))}>Delete</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(editItem(productId, index))}>Edit</button>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(addItem(productId))}>Add</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Reducer:**

```
case types.UPDATE_PRODUCT: {
  console.log('update')
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product, i) =>
      i == action.index
        ? {
            ...product,
            editable: product.editable == true ? false : true,
          }
        : product
    ),
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope **toggle** from and to *Edit and View* mode is working for you.

Now if your question is:

> How to modify the product details (title, description, etc.) after a
>   particular product item is in edit mode?

Here is how you can do it:

- Wrap your input fields in `form`, make it [uncontrolled](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html) by using `defaultValue` instead of `value`
- place a `input` button of type `submit` (it will let you submit the form by hitting **ENTER** in any field, **hide** it with `CSS` if you don't want to show it):

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <input
    name="title"
    ref={this.title}
    defaultValue={product.title}
    // value={product.title}
  />
  <input
    name="description"
    ref={this.description}
    defaultValue={product.description}
    // value={product.description}
  />
  <input
    type="submit"
    value="submit"
    className="display-none"
    style={{ display: 'none' }}
  />
</form>
```

and `handleSubmit` function:

```
handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  e.stopPropagation()

  // you can use event to read form field values
  console.debug(e.target.title.value)
  console.debug(e.target.description.value)

  // or use the element Ref you created 
  console.debug(this.title.current.value)
  console.debug(this.description.current.value)

  // Here, you can make API call or dispatch action to your redux to update the data
}
```

**Few other points:**

- Provide some other value to [`key`](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) instead of `index` if possible, e.g. product id
- You can use `editable: !product.editable` in your reducer instead of `editable: product.editable == true ? false : true`
- Use `id` if possible to find which product to update in your reducer instead of `index` : <del>(`products.map((product, i) => i == action.index ?`)</del>
- Use `===` to compare instead of `==`, [more on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2873538)

Comment: Thanks, this is a quite extended explanation and I think the solution is that by using defaultValue it made the input field editable. Not sure why, but I run this app with a server client.

Comment: When you set `value` attribute of a form element in react with some value (literal or variable), this value becomes [single source of truth](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) of its value and would not change at UI until that source is changed. But `defaultValue` will provide the value to element only once at render, after that it won't control the value of element.

Answer (score 0):

you can try using the boolean value in readonly attribute of inputfield

```
<input readOnly={product.editable} />
```

Comment: But how can I edit the value inside input field then?

Comment: if the attribute is false you would be allowed to edit.
if your requirement is different can you ellaborate it?

Comment: but how do I get the same value of product.title and product.description inside the input field and then make it editable